# spacing in a TikZ tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I have created a Work Breakdown Structure and I'm having trouble spacing The levels so they don't overlap.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}


\begin{document}
\hspace{-140pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners=3pt, semithick, drop shadow},
            ROOT/.style = {fill=blue!20, inner sep=2mm, font=\bfseries},
              L1/.style = {fill=blue!20},
              L2/.style = {fill=orange!30, sibling distance=50mm},
              L3/.style = {fill=green!90},
              L4/.style = {fill=green!40, grow=down, xshift=-0.9em, anchor=west, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
              L5/.style = {fill=green!10, grow=down, xshift=-0.9em, anchor=west, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
edge from parent/.style = {draw, thick},
              LD/.style = {level distance=#1ex},
             LD1/.style = {level distance=8ex},
             LD2/.style = {level distance=16ex},
             LD3/.style = {level distance=24ex},
             LD4/.style = {level distance=32ex},
             LD5/.style = {level distance=40ex},
             LD6/.style = {level distance=48ex},
             LD7/.style = {level distance=56ex},
             LD8/.style = {level distance=64ex},
             LD9/.style = {level distance=72ex},
             LD10/.style = {level distance=80ex},
             LD11/.style = {level distance=88ex},
             LD12/.style = {level distance=96ex},
         level 1/.style = {sibling distance=35mm},
                        ]
    % Parents
\node[ROOT] {1 M-C19}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child{node[L2] {1.1 Vehicle}
      [edge from parent fork down]
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1 \\Fuselage\\ \end{tabular}}
        child[L4,LD1]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.1 \\Cockpit\\ \end{tabular}}
          child[L5,LD1]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.1.1\\Instruments\\ \end{tabular}}}
          child[L5,LD2]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.1.2\\Seats\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
        child[L4,LD4]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2 \\Body\\ \end{tabular}}
           child[L5,LD1]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.1\\Cargo holdings\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD2]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.2\\Seats\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD3]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.3\\W.C. \\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=33.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.4\\Onboard \\comfort system\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=43]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.5\\Cargo loading\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=51]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.6\\Doors\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=59]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.7\\Body shell\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
      }
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2 \\Wing\\ \end{tabular}}
        child[L4,LD1]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.1 \\Wing body\\ \end{tabular}}
           child[L5,LD=9.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.1.1\\Structural\\ analysis\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=20.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.1.2\\Aerodynamic\\ analysis\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
        child[L4,LD5]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2 \\Auxiliar elements\\ \end{tabular}}
           child[L5,LD1]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.1\\Flaps\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD2]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.2\\Ailerons\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD3]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.3\\Winglets \\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD4]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.4\\Slats\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.5\\Stall system analysis\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
        child[L4,LD11]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.3 \\Wing unions\\ \end{tabular}}
           child[L5,LD1]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.3.1\\Fuselage-wing\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD2]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.3.2\\Engine-wing\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
      }
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.3 \\Tail\\ \end{tabular}}
        child[L5,LD=9.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.3.1 \\Horizontal \\stabilizer\\ \end{tabular}}}
        child[L5,LD=20.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.3.2 \\Vertical \\stabilizer\\ \end{tabular}}}
      }
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.4 \\Engine\\ \end{tabular}}}
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.5 \\Landing gear\\ \end{tabular}}}
      }
    child{node[L2] {1.2 Project Management}
      child[L5,LD1]  {node[L5]   {B1}}
      child[L5,LD2]  {node[L5]   {B2}}
            }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to ask you to tell us the source of your code. Did you write all of that by yourself? If so, congratulations, and you will find it very easy to complete the tree. If not, then you may want to give credit to those who provided you with that code. BTW, there is a `;` missing at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that fixes the problems in a very ad hoc way. I did however not attempt to clean up the code. In particular, I did not eliminate the duplication of node styles. If you disclose the source of your code, I will be happy to invest more energy in this. Rather likely it will be more efficient to switch to forest for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}


\begin{document}
%\hspace{-140pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners=3pt, semithick, drop shadow},
            ROOT/.style = {fill=blue!20, inner sep=2mm, font=\bfseries},
              L1/.style = {fill=blue!20},
              L2/.style = {fill=orange!30, sibling distance=50mm},
              L3/.style = {fill=green!90},
              L4/.style = {fill=green!40, grow=down, xshift=-0.9em, anchor=west, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
              L5/.style = {fill=green!10, grow=down, xshift=-0.9em, anchor=west, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
edge from parent/.style = {draw, thick},
              LD/.style = {level distance=#1ex},
             LD1/.style = {level distance=8ex},
             LD2/.style = {level distance=16ex},
             LD3/.style = {level distance=24ex},
             LD4/.style = {level distance=32ex},
             LD5/.style = {level distance=40ex},
             LD6/.style = {level distance=48ex},
             LD7/.style = {level distance=56ex},
             LD8/.style = {level distance=64ex},
             LD9/.style = {level distance=72ex},
             LD10/.style = {level distance=80ex},
             LD11/.style = {level distance=88ex},
             LD12/.style = {level distance=96ex},
         level 1/.style = {sibling distance=35mm},
                        ]
    % Parents
\node[ROOT] {1 M-C19}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child{node[L2] {1.1 Vehicle}
      [edge from parent fork down]
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1 \\Fuselage\\ \end{tabular}}
        child[L4,LD1]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.1 \\Cockpit\\ \end{tabular}}
          child[L5,LD1]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.1.1\\Instruments\\ \end{tabular}}}
          child[L5,LD2]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.1.2\\Seats\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
        child[L4,LD4]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2 \\Body\\ \end{tabular}}
           child[L5,LD1]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.1\\Cargo holdings\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD2]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.2\\Seats\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD3]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.3\\W.C. \\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=33.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.4\\Onboard \\comfort system\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=43]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.5\\Cargo loading\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=51]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.6\\Doors\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=59]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.1.2.7\\Body shell\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
      }
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2 \\Wing\\ \end{tabular}}
        child[L4,LD1]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.1 \\Wing body\\ \end{tabular}}
           child[L5,LD=9.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.1.1\\Structural\\ analysis\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD=20.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.1.2\\Aerodynamic\\ analysis\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
        child[L4,LD5]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2 \\Auxiliar elements\\ \end{tabular}}
           child[L5,LD1]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.1\\Flaps\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD2]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.2\\Ailerons\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD3]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.3\\Winglets \\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD4]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.4\\Slats\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.2.5\\Stall system analysis\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
        child[L4,LD11]   {node[L4]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.3 \\Wing unions\\ \end{tabular}}
           child[L5,LD1]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.3.1\\Fuselage-wing\\ \end{tabular}}}
           child[L5,LD2]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.2.3.2\\Engine-wing\\ \end{tabular}}}
        }
      }
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.3 \\Tail\\ \end{tabular}}
        child[L5,LD=9.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.3.1 \\Horizontal \\stabilizer\\ \end{tabular}}}
        child[L5,LD=20.5]   {node[L5]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.3.2 \\Vertical \\stabilizer\\ \end{tabular}}}
      }
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.4 \\Engine\\ \end{tabular}}}
      child[L3,LD1]   {node[L3]   {\begin{tabular}{l} 1.1.5 \\Landing gear\\ \end{tabular}}}
      }
    child{node[L2] (PM) {1.2 Project Management}
            };
    \node[right=1cm of PM,L5] (B2)  {B2};
    \node[above=5mm of B2,L5] (B1)  {B1};
    \draw[thick] (PM) -- (B2) coordinate[midway] (aux);
    \draw[thick] (aux) |- (B1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]